# on a property of nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that *for every* nilpotent $B$ we have
$$AB = 0$$

Is $A$ necessarily zero?

Comment: I don't get your reasoning, but obviously $A:=B^{k-1}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: AB = 0 for every nilpotent B

Comment: That’s a different problem. If that is what you mean, then say so...

Comment: sorry for my mistake with the quantifiers

Comment: And if that is the problem, then your argument is nonsensical, as it is about the problem stated, not the one intended. More so for the assertion that $AB^{k-1}$ must be zero, or that $A$ must be zero from that. Neither assertion follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is not correct because if $MN=0$ and $N\neq0$, we cannot conclude that $M=0$.

The claim

> Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $AB=0$ for every nilpotent matrix $B$. Then $A=0$.

is true so long as the dimension $n$ is greater than $1$. Let $B$ be a matrix which is all zero except the $i$-th element of the first column, which is $1$. Then if $i>1$, $B$ is nilpotent and $AB$ is a matrix which is all zero, except that the $i$-th column of $AB$ is the $i$-th column of $A$. Therefore $AB=0$ implies the $i$-th column of $A$ is zero.

This only works for $i>1$ since when $i=1$, the matrix $B$ so described is not nilpotent. But we can take a slightly different $B$, all zero except the first entry of the second column, which is $1$. Then $AB$ is all zero except the first column is the same as in $A$, so $AB=0$ implies the first column of $A$ is zero. Therefore all columns of $A$ are zero and $A=0$.

When the dimension $n$ is $1$ the claim is false since the only nilpotent $1\times1$ matrix is $0$.

Comment: @James Since $AB=0$ for all nilpotent $B$, I am carefully choosing $B$-s so as to be able to claim that each individual column of $A$ is zero, and therefore $A$ is zero.